# How can i call a soap web service that changed from http to https?

Tags: java, cxf, java-ws

I tried to call a web service that changed recently from HTTP to HTTPS and I get this error :

```
    java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server
```

Note that i had issues with certificates but i added them in the truststore via keytool, then i set System properties with:

```
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "C://Progra~1//Java//jdk1.8.0_201//jre//lib//security//cacerts");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword","changeit");
```

The error that appears:

```
main, handling exception: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset main, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, description = unexpected_message main, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2 main, 
Exception sending alert: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error main, called closeSocket()
```

thank you in advance for your intervention!

Comment: What errors do you encounter?

Comment: `main, handling exception: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
main, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, description = unexpected_message
main, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
main, Exception sending alert: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
main, called closeSocket()`

Answer (score 1):

Adnane, while trying to run the client you can set extra parameter which will print debug logs on ssl connection negotiation with server.

This way you can check if certificate chain is correct and rule out if it is related to certificates.

```
-Djavax.net.debug=all
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. can you explain this response : 'main, handling exception: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
main, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, description = unexpected_message
main, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
main, Exception sending alert: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
main, called closeSocket()'

Comment: here is the log : [link](https://pastebin.com/LtwgTSwN)

Comment: There is definitely no issue with certificate chain as I can see

0000: 47 45 54 20 2F 57 73 44   65 63 65 2E 61 73 6D 78  GET /WsDece.asmx
0010: 3F 57 53 44 4C 20 48 54   54 50 2F 31 2E 31 0D 0A  ?WSDL HTTP/1.1..

and server response

0000: 48 54 54 50 2F 31 2E 31   20 32 30 30 20 4F 4B 0D  HTTP/1.1 200 OK.

But I am not able to understand
INFOS: Creating Service {http://interieur.gov.ma/ec/dece}WsDece from WSDL: https://ec-ws-part.cloud.interieur.gov.ma/WsDece.asmx?WSDL
Invoking getDeces...

Comment: The interesting thing is that's work fine in Soapui.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problème by setting the header as :

```
Map<String, Object> req_ctx = ((BindingProvider) port).getRequestContext();
    req_ctx.put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY,wsdlURL.toString());          
    Map<String, List<String>> headers = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
    headers.put("Content-Type", Collections.singletonList("text/xml"));        
    req_ctx.put(MessageContext.HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS, headers);
```

the content type was "application/xml".